# Dividing tension of a string in pendulum and then calculating with weight

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, vectors, free-body-diagram

One of my teachers in my school showed me a way to calculate the force  acting on a pendulum. He did it in two ways:
W= weight of bob
T= tension of string and its length cannot change
A= The angle made with the equilibrium

1. First he divided the gravitational force in two components. Then he showed that the only force is $W sinA$ which is perpendicular to the string. $W cosA$ and $T$ is equal and opposite in direction.
2. Then he divided the tension in two components. Then he showed that the only force is $T sinA$ which is perpendicular to$W$. Also$T cosA$ and $W$ is equal and opposite in direction.
   Now I am having trouble with method  In this method the force acting upon bob doesn't follow the bob's path of motion.

   From above I got:
   $W cosA=T$ and $T cosA=W$
   By solving I got : $A=90$ which means both methods are only valid for $A=90$. So I think method two is not right. 
   Can anyone tell me if both methods are right? If both are right, then why am I having difficulty with these equation?

NB: Forgive me for my English. I am having trouble uploading pictures.

Comment: Taking component of $T$ is not necessary (I think) , cause tension remains the same all along ...

Comment: @Nehal Samee I think $T$ changes with$W$ and remains equal to $W cosA$.

Comment: When $A→0$ , then $W.cos A= W$ ... SO , $T$ remains constant ...

Answer (score 0):

In both cases he is using small angle approximations which are accurate to better than $1\%$ as long as angle $a$ is less than $5^\circ$

$$\sin a\approx a \text{ and } \cos a\approx 1$$

> I got: $W \cos A=T$ and $T \cos A=W$
>    By solving I got : $A=90^\circ$.

These two equation are both approximately true if $A< 5^\circ$

—-

The other thing to note is that the pendulum bob of mass $m$ is moving is a circular motion, of radius $l$ which is the length of the string,  and so has a centripetal acceleration of $\frac {v^2}{l}$ where $v$ is the speed of the bob.

So $T-W\cos A=  m\frac {v^2}{l}$ and using the small angle approximation your teacher has assumed the the centripetal acceleration of the pendulum bob is approximately zero with $T-W\cos A \approx 0$

Comment: Is method 2 right for all angles?

Comment: Is method 1 also right for all angles?

Comment: Use method $1$ and remember that if you trying to show the motion is simple harmonic then the angle must be less than $5^\circ$.

Comment: So method 2 is wrong for bigger angles and why is that? If I am not to show the motion is simple harmonic then can I use method 1 for all angles?

Comment: Whichever method you use the angle must be less than $5^\circ$ if you wish to show that the motion is simple harmonic.  Method 2 is more complicated if you wish to include the centripetal acceleration.

Comment: Kindly just tell me one thing clearly. Is method 2 right for all angles?